# Best way to get object data?

Tags: c#, delegates, xna

I need to display some stats, numbers, and graphs about various game objects on the screen.

(examples: camera position, field of view, frames per second, fill rate, number of objects culled, etc... )

Currently any object which wants to be graphed or displayed implements an interface along these lines:

```
public interface IGraphable
{
    float GraphableValue { get; set; }
}
```

Then that object can be sent to a graph component to be displayed. This has some obvious drawbacks like not being able to graph 2 different pieces of data which belong to the same class.

What I want is a way to pass a pointer to where the data is located or a pointer to a function which knows how to return the data instead of passing the object to the display component.

I believe that this is what delegates are for but I don't understand how to use them in this context (Actually I don't understand them very well at all). Also, is there another (smarter/better) way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have decided to do the following:

```
public class GraphComponent
{
   private Func<flaot> _function;

   public GraphComponent(Func<flaot> function, ...)
   { ... }
}
```

This allows me to specify how the data is retrieved by writing something like this:

```
FPSComponent fpsc = new FPSComponent();    
GraphComponent fpsg = new GraphComponent(delegate() { return fpsc.ApproximateFPS; }, ...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not invert the control like this:

```
public interface IGraphable
{
    void BuildGraphable( IGraph g );
}

interface IGraph {
    void AddValue( double value );
}
```

this is a preferred option in OO anyway as it hides details of the IGraphable implementation. Additionally you can now extend IGraph for added functionality without breaking compatibility.

Comment: I actually had it this way before. I changed it because every graph component can have its own update frequency (lets say 7 times per second). If the graph component were updated by the IGraphable class I would not be able to have an independent update frequency for the graph component. (for example a camera may be updated 60 times per second but the graph showing field of view (lol at graphing "field of view") may not need to be updated that often...)

Comment: You call method 60 times a second, or ask for a property 60 times a second, there isn't a difference. One gives you the potential to collect several pieces of data, while the other returns just one.

Comment: there is a difference, it wastes computation by adding or updating the value.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you're doing things, you could possibly use Reflection (attributes on accessors), although that can be relatively confusing at first too. But it's a very useful tool in your arsenal, so it's well worth spending the time on. Here is a great tutorial on how to use them:

http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/C_Sharp/Attributes.htm

But then, learning delegates is also very useful, and that does sound like a good solution. I haven't looked deeply into it, but this tutorial on the same site might be useful:

http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/C_Sharp/Delegates_and_Event_Handlers.htm

Comment: Thanks for the link! I will look into it. However, I have heard that reflection is very slow. Is this true? (I understand that slow is a relative term)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure about speeds of reflection. My guess would be that it's not as fast as just calling a method (as delegates would let you do). You probably wouldn't want to be using reflection if it's going to be called a million times a second. But I could be wrong ;-) I don't spend a heap of time using them.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want is a way to pass a pointer to where the data is located or a pointer to a function which knows how to return the data instead of passing the object to the display component.

If you don't want to add your objects to your graph component BECAUSE

> This has some obvious drawbacks like not being able to graph 2 different pieces of data which belong to the same class.

Maybe a list will solve your problem ?

```
public interface IGraphable
{
    List<float> GraphableValues { get; }
}
```